# jQuery - replace a word in text with a variable value

Tags: jquery, replace, innerhtml

All I could figure out how to do with jQuery replace was to replace specific text to a specific text.
Unfortunately I am not able to do this with a variable.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
$("#id").html($("#id").html().replace(/myVariableHere/g, 'hello'));
```

myVariableHere - this is where I want to put a variable. If I hardcode a text there, everything works fine. But as this value will be dynamic (depending on what you click), I must put a variable there, not a hardcoded word...
What is wrong with my syntax?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Actually replace() has nothing to do with jQuery, it is pure javascript, but nevertheless a very good question

Answer (score 2):

RegExp Object instead of literal form :

```
var patt=new RegExp(myVariableHere,'g');
$("#id").html($("#id").html().replace(patt, 'hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use Regexes at all?

```
$("#id").html($("#id").html().replace(myVariableHere, 'hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you're doing the replacements on the HTML contents of the element (which is what `.html()` returns/sets), you're actually replacing the HTML code, including tag names, classes, etc. So, if the text that you're replacing happens to be a HTML tag or a class name, you could break the document. To avoid that, traverse the child nodes of the parent element and only do the replacements on text nodes:

```
function replaceText($elem, text, replacement) {
    // Check if the element has just one child, and the child is a text node
    if ($elem[0].childNodes.length == 1 && $elem[0].firstChild.nodeType == 3)
        $elem.text($elem.text().replace(text, replacement));
    else
        // Call the replacement function on each child element
        $elem.children().each(function () {
            replaceText($(this), text, replacement);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below snippet

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(old_word, new_word));
```

with $(this) being the object containing the text you want to replace